# Password reset url is no longer active

Tags: url, passwords

Password resets have been being handled by a script. Now the server that the script was running on has been retired. I can't find where to set the password reset url to the gmail default. Any help would be appreciated.

The path the user takes is
settings => See all settings => Accounts => Google account Settings => security => password

This takes the user to a broken link.

Answer (score 0):

In the Admin Dashboard choose

1. Domains
2. Click the hamburger in the top left corner
3. choose Security
4. choose Set up single sign-on with 3rd party IdP
5. Remove Change password URL
6. Click Save